# Mass of $B$ Meson

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, quarks, mesons

This is a question from Griffith's Introduction to Elementary Particles, Chapter 2:  The upsilon meson, $b\bar b$, is the bottom-quark analog to the $\psi$, $c\bar c$. Its mass is 9460
MeV/$c^2$ and its lifetime is 1.5 X $10^{-20}$ sec. From this information, what can you say about the mass of the [$B$ meson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_meson) $u\bar b$ (The observed mass is 5270 MeV/$c^2$.)
All I can think of is that since $b\bar b$  has a mass of 9460 MeV/$c^2$, the individual bottom quark must be having a mass of 4730 MeV/$c^2$. Could someone give a hint as to how to proceed from here?

Comment: It is not that simple, see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/quark.html

Comment: But then, aren't we supposed to know the mass of up quark beforehand to solve this question? Also, the mass for the bottom quark in the link is almost the same as what I found. Is this the way to proceed?

Comment: "what can you say" , might mean "upper limits", the way the lin treats it.

Comment: I'm not quite getting how I am supposed to proceed with this question, could you please elaborate?

Comment: if you study the numbers in the link, for example the masses estimated by scattering for the up and down, you will see that a lot of the mass of the pion , ~140MeV, is very much larger than adding the mass of the two quarks. in the quantum mechanical theory the binding of the two quarks is done by a sea of virtual gluons etc, whose four vectors add up to the pion mass as a bound state. So the number 140/2 can only be given as an upper estimate for the up and down quark mass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add more detail to @AjayShanmugaSakthivasan 's answer, such heavy-quark -onia systems such as  Υ and J/ψ entail quark-antiquark pairs bound by some QCD effective potential. The heavier the quarks, the *deeper* the location of the pair in such potentials, and the *more* the energy required to liberate the quarks and have them subsequently bind (much more weakly) to charmed and bottomed mesons, Ds and Bs, respectively.

For the J/ψ, of mass 3.1 GeV in natural units, you need to add a bit of energy to pull the charmed quarks out of the potentials, and then a bit more to create a light quark-antiquark pair to hadronize to some type of constituent form binding (much heavier than the current quarks you'd find in the PDG, the gist of @anna v 's comment) into D mesons (each of 1.9 GeV), so you need to add about 0.6 GeV.

For the Υ, you need to add (2×5.28- 9.46) GeV ~ 1.1 GeV to do the same, since the b$\bar b$ pair is deeper in the binding potential.
The deficit of so much energy prevents such decays and  condemns the respective Onia to only decay into light hadrons, through three intermediate  gluons, suppressed by the OZI rule. Conversely, knowing that these Onia are stabilized by the OZI suppression, you can estimate that the charmed or bottomed mesons must be heavier than half the Onia mass by a serious fraction of a GeV...

Answer (score 1):

[@anna v](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1492/anna-v) gave you an example, the pion, as to why you cannot expect the mass of the meson to be equal to the mass of the constituent quarks. Most of the contribution to hadron mass is not from the constituent quarks, typically.

But what you can say about this particular meson, the $\Upsilon$ meson, is that it has a relatively longer lifetime for strong mediated decay, shorter for electromagnetic decay. This is usually the case of **OZI-suppressed** systems (see, for example, the $J/\Psi$ meson). This implies that a direct decay into $B$-$\bar{B}$ mesons must be kinematically prohibited, otherwise this channel would shorten the lifetime of $\Upsilon$ to the typical $\sim 10^{-24} s$ of a strong mediated decay. Note that, $\Upsilon \rightarrow B\bar{B}$ will not be OZI-suppressed. Therefore, you can conclude that $B$ (and $\bar{B}$) mesons must have a mass greater than $4730\,\text{MeV}/\text{c}^2$.